# too many values error while using rowtype in procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
CREATE OR replace PACKAGE emp_pkg 
AS 
  PROCEDURE find_emp1( 
    c_id IN employees.employee_id%TYPE); 
END emp_pkg; 

/ 
CREATE OR replace PACKAGE BODY emp_pkg 
AS 
  PROCEDURE Find_emp1(c_id IN employees.employee_id%TYPE) 
  IS 
    v_row employees%ROWTYPE; 
  BEGIN 
      SELECT first_name, 
             employee_id, 
             hire_date 
      INTO   v_row 
      FROM   employees 
      WHERE  employee_id = c_id; 

      dbms_output.Put_line('ID:' 
                           || v_row.employee_id); 

      dbms_output.Put_line('NAME:' 
                           ||v_row.first_name); 

      dbms_output.Put_line('HIRE_DATE:' 
                           || v_row.hire_date); 
  END find_emp1; 
END emp_pkg; 

/
```

Comment: It means that employee_id is not UNIQUE. I suggest to check your data and add PRIMARY KEY on that column(if applicable).

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a mismatch between the 3 values in the select statement and the number of columns in your table. What are the table columns?